# Is it possible to convert the Google MediaPipe FaceMeshV2 TFLite model with post-training quantization to a fully integer-quantized model version?

Tags: tensorflow, mediapipe, google-coral, quantization-aware-training, face-mesh

I am seeking assistance regarding the conversion of the [MediaPipe FaceMeshV2 model](https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/vision/face_landmarker) for use with the [Coral EdgeTPU Accelerator](https://coral.ai/products/accelerator/). As per the Coral documentation, a model must undergo full integer quantization before it can be compiled for the Coral using their [EdgeTPU Compiler](https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/compiler/).

I have discovered quantized FaceMeshV2 models in [this](https://github.com/PINTO0309/PINTO_model_zoo) model zoo, but unfortunately, they are not functioning correctly. I have experimented with quantized [FaceMeshV1](https://github.com/PINTO0309/PINTO_model_zoo/tree/main/032_FaceMesh) models from the same source, and they work without issue, indicating that my testing methodology is accurate. However, I am particularly interested in utilizing FaceMeshV2 due to its superior accuracy in detecting facial landmarks.

The [TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization#full_integer_quantization) outlines the process of post-training quantization for existing TFLite models, but full integer quantization requires a representative dataset, which I am struggling to acquire. I have not attempted the conversion process yet due to this challenge.

My primary inquiry is whether the described conversion is feasible, as I have found limited resources on the topic, and the converted model obtained from [Pinto](https://github.com/PINTO0309/PINTO_model_zoo) is not functioning correctly. Could it be that the model's architecture is hindering the conversion process? Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.